# How to create an AWS role for a Django Application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I have a Django app and I want to create an AWS IAM role for it. I want to do this so that I can get access to AWS Secrets Manager, among other AWS services. How do I set this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with the following [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "<arn-to-your-secrete>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The above policy is based on the example from AWS docs:

- [Allow read access to specific secrets in AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconnect/latest/ug/iam-policy-examples-asm-secrets.html#iam-policy-examples-asm-specific-secrets)